# jQuery validate plugin - how to NOT show the "this field is required" labels

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How do I turn off the displaying of "this field is required" for ALL of my input text boxes?  I'd rather not have to do something like this:

```
$("myForm").validate({
  messages: { myField1: { required: '' }, myField2: { required: '' }, myField3: { required: '' }}
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply set the default required message to empty string.

```
$.validator.messages.required = '';
```

Comment: do u know if it makes a difference for when I include this snippet?  before or after my `$("#myForm").validate()`?

Answer (score 3):

There are  a varierty of ways:

- Use errorPlacement callback to over ride default insertion of error labels with your own function
- Use errorLabelContainer option to place error elements all in one container and hide container
- set validator default messages to empty string - see docs setDefaults
- use css to hide label.error

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a class to each of the items and then loop over that class and cross check their type as input

```
$(".frmPrc").each(function(index) {
                    if ($(this).attr("type")=="checkbox") {
                        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                            arrFrmData.push({ "ID":index, "Field":$(this).attr("id"), "Value":1, "Title":$(this).attr("title")});
                        } else {
                            arrFrmData.push({ "ID":index, "Field":$(this).attr("id"), "Value":0, "Title":$(this).attr("title")});
                        }
                    } else if ($(this).attr("type")=="radio") {
                        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                            arrFrmData.push({ "ID":index, "Field":$(this).attr("name"), "Value":$(this).val(), "Title":$(this).attr("title")});
                        }
                    } else {
                        arrFrmData.push({ "ID":index, "Field":$(this).attr("id"), "Value":$(this).val(), "Title":$(this).attr("title")});
                    }
                });
```

this is just a quick copy and paste from an old script... as you can see, it can be shortened... but gives the basic idea of using "required" fields...

Answer (score 0):

I used to add a class to all input elements instead of using Validate Plugins, that are to validate:

```
<input type="text" class=toValidate/>
```

....

```
   function validateForm(){
        $(".toValidate").each(function (){
          if($(this).val()==""){
            do something
}
        })
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Only do this and your problem will be solved!

```
var validator = $("#MyForm").validate({errorPlacement: function() {
    return true;
}});
```