# Hide 'This field is required' not working in Azure site

Tags: jquery, angularjs, azure

I'm trying to hide the 'This field is required' message in my views. I added 'NoValidate' to my form tag and while in VS 2015, I do not see the text. But when I publish my site to Azure, it shows up. Can someone tell me if I can hide this text in an Azure site? I tried the suggestions in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904843/jquery-validate-plugin-how-to-not-show-the-this-field-is-required-labels) (in code below) and it still did not work.

Simplified version of one of my views

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" novalidate ng-app="LoginApp" 
    ng-controller="LoginController">
    <input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" class="form-control 
        validateIt" placeholder="Email" ng-model="emailAddress" required autofocus />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".validateIt").keyup(function () {
        checkIsFormValid();
    });
});

var form = $("#loginForm");

function checkIsFormValid() {
    $.validator.messages.required = '';
    form.validate();

    var validator = $("#loginForm").validate({
        errorPlacement: function () {
            return true;
        }
    });

    if (form.valid()) {
        $('#submitLoginForm').removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $('#submitLoginForm').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it in document ready and it did not work. I moved it out to global area, and it worked. If you want to move your comment to an answer, I'll mark it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can keep your `$.validator.messages.required = '';` either in `document.ready` or somewhere globally in `js`. The scope of the `validator` would be very limit when you keep it inside the `function` and it would execute only when `function` is called and executed.